# Android ScrollView inside RecyclerView.ViewHolder: prevent ItemTouchHelper from getting touch event?

Tags: android, scrollview, itemtouchhelper

Setup: I have a `RecyclerView` with a `vertical LinearLayoutManager`. Each `ViewHolder` has 2 `TextViews` (green and red in the picture), which can be very long. `RED` can be scrolled horizontally thanks to a `HorizontalScrollView`. `GREEN` can be scrolled vertically thanks to a `ScrollView`.

Now I have implemented `ItemTouchHelper`, to swipe LEFT, UP or DOWN. The problem is that my `ScrollViews` don't work anymore. Instead, even when I swipe `GREEN` UP or DOWN, it is my `ViewHolder` that moves. **How do I prevent my `ItemTouchHelper` from getting the touch event?**

I've tried:

-`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

-`NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

-implementing `setOnTouchListener` inside my adapter to return `true` (the listener is triggered, but the event is not consumed)

-thought about using `RecyclerView.findChildViewUnder` inside `onChildDraw` to scroll manually and block the `super` method but I can't find a way to get the coordinates

Nothing works so far. How do I do this? Here is my `ItemTouchHelper`:

```
private fun enableSwipe() {
        val simpleItemTouchCallback =
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE, ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    val content = mAdapter.getContentForPosition(position)

                    //do stuff...
                }
            }

            override fun onChildDraw(
                c: Canvas,
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                dX: Float,
                dY: Float,
                actionState: Int,
                isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
            ) {

                val mdX = if (abs(dY) > abs(dX)) {
                    0f
                }else{
                    dX
                }
                val mdY = if (abs(dY) > abs(dX)) {
                    when{
                        dY > 0 ->  if (dY > 500f) 500f else dY
                        else -> if (dY < -500f) -500f else dY
                    }

                }else{
                    0f
                }
                //override viewHolder in case we swipe up or down on the other content
                val mViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = if (abs(dY) > abs(dX)) {
                            if (dY < 0) {
                                //swiping up
                                getViewHolder(1) ?: viewHolder
                            } else {
                                getViewHolder(0) ?: viewHolder
                            }
                        }else {
                    viewHolder
                }

                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, mViewHolder, mdX, mdY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            }
        }
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewClash)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only thing that works, finally found it. It is important to understand that the `ItemTouchHelper` will implement `onItemTouchListener`:

> An [OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html) allows the application to intercept touch events in progress at the view hierarchy level of the RecyclerView **before those touch events are considered for RecyclerView's own scrolling behavior**.

```
textView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        //let the scrollView handle the scroll event
        scrollView.onTouchEvent(event)
        //this is the key feature
        v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        //return true to consume the event (mandatory)
        true
}
```

Nothing else is needed. Also, a `ScrollView` is enough, no need for a `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: can you be more specific as to where to implement the code

Comment: @TejasSherdiwala inside the  RecyclerView's Adapter. This is a TextView wrapped sinde a ScrollView

Comment: This solution disables flick scrolling. You literally have to scroll the content all the way till the end.